# What is a Richi Word™?

Tags: pattern, language, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Richi Word™**.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{1}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Richi }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  CUB }&\text{ BEAR }\\ \hline
\text{  AIR }&\text{ WATER }\\ \hline
\text{  WEB }&\text{ NET }\\ \hline
\text{  MOOD }&\text{ MIND }\\ \hline
\text{  MISS }&\text{ FAIL }\\ \hline
\text{  PLAY }&\text{ WORK }\\ \hline
\text{  NOPE }&\text{ YUP }\\ \hline
\text{  GRIND }&\text{ POLISH }\\ \hline
\text{  BLACK }&\text{ WHITE }\\ \hline
\text{  DECODE }&\text{ ENCODE }\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Richi Words™,Not Richi Words™
CUB,BEAR
AIR,WATER
WEB,NET
MOOD,MIND
MISS,FAIL
PLAY,WORK
NOPE,YUP
GRIND,POLISH
BLACK,WHITE
DECODE,ENCODE
```

Hint 1:

> [image]

Hint 2:

> Added **Language** tag here. The title may be applicable, but the rule for **Richi Word™** is not.

Hint 3:

> $3n+2-1$

Comment: I might need a hint for this one

Comment: @GrumpyLlama59 Here it is :)

Comment: Does this need the `Language` tag?

Comment: Hmm, Let me think :P

Comment: I've had the connection that the hints are pointing to since the puzzle was posted (though surely that should be "ii" rather than "i"?). I just don't know how to *use* that connection.

Comment: @Deusovi nice finding :P (I just let ī = i for convenience, double i should be correct too.)

Comment: I'm in the same boat as @Deusovi I reckon - I know what it's based _on_, but quite how to derive the _numbers_ I don't know! Still, my last half hour has taught me a lot about symbols I never knew you could make in Unicode!

Answer (score 13):

I think the answer is

> Convert the letters in a given word to numbers as A=1, B=2, ..., Z=26, then consider the collection of digits. Then all the Richi words allow you to **[declare Riichi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_Mahjong#Riichi)** with those digits; that is, if you add one more digit, you can form one or more melds and exactly one pair, thus forming a *winning hand* in Mahjong.
>
> A *meld* is a group of three digits, which is either a *triplet* (three copies of single digit, e.g. `333`) or a *sequence* (three adjacent digits, e.g. `567`). A *pair* is two copies of single digit, e.g. `11`.
>
> Using `GRIND` as an example: `GRIND = 7 18 9 14 4`, and sorting the digits gives `1144789`. If you add a 1 to the collection, you get `111 44 789` which is one triplet `111`, one sequence `789`, and a pair `44`, which is a winning hand.
>
> <sup>I guess I was lucky here because I'm an active Japanese Mahjong player :)</sup>

Proof for the given Richi words:

> The missing digit from the winning hand is marked in parens.
>
> ```
> CUB = 3 21 2 = 123 2(2)
> AIR = 1 9 18 = 11 (7)89
> WEB = 23 5 2 = 22 3(4)5
> MOOD = 13 15 15 4 = 111 (2)34 55 or 111 34(5) 55 or 111 345 5(5)
> MISS = 13 9 19 19 = 111 3(3) 999 or 11 1(2)3 999
> PLAY = 16 12 1 25 = 111 22 (4)56 or 111 22 56(7)
> NOPE = 14 15 16 5 = 111 456 5(5)
> GRIND = 7 18 9 14 4 = 11(1) 44 789 or 11 44(4) 789
> BLACK = 2 12 1 3 11 = 111 123 2(2) or 11 123 12(3)
> DECODE = 4 5 3 15 4 5 = 1(2)3 44 555
> ```

Proof for the given non-Richi words:

> In order to be a Richi word, a word must give exactly $3n+2-1$ digits when converted. Most of the given words do not meet this criteria, except for POLISH and WHITE. I guess WHITE is disqualified because it contains a 0 at T=20 (there's no 0 tile in Mahjong), and `POLISH = 16 15 12 9 19 8 = 1111256899` is pretty far from a winning hand.

Connections to the hints:

> Hint 1 is a picture of a sparrow (I think). Japanese Mahjong is 麻雀 in Kanji, and 雀 means a sparrow.

> Hint 2: Richi (more precisely Riichi/Rīchi) is a Japanese word, though it is a specific term only used in Japanese Mahjong.

> Hint 3 is the formula for the number of tiles for a ready hand (where you can declare Riichi). A winning hand has $3n + 2$ tiles ($3n$ for one or more melds and $2$ for the pair), and a ready hand is 1 tile away from that, which is represented as $-1$.

Comment: excellent solution!,